# Google checkout integration - didn't find on docs/guides/Google

Tags: google-checkout

When I sent a POST to Google checkout API, the return XML (or HTML) auto redirects the user to Google to complete the checkout.

I understand pci compliance and why this is needed, but is there a way to submit the user's info in the background so they don't have to leave my site to checkout? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that with Google Checkout.

Check out stripe.com - similar pricing, but much easier integration!  I just started using them and it's been a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selling digital or virtual goods cosider Google In-App Payments which integrates nicely with your site and offers an in-app purchase experience for the user.

http://www.google.com/payments/payment-options/digital-goods.html